# The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the type 'Trending'

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding, geofencing

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('admin')
    .doc('Geofence')
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  geofenceModel = geofenceModel.fromMap//error here(value.data());
  setState(() {
    latitude = ("${geofenceModel.latitude}");
    longitude = ("${geofenceModel.longitude}");
    radius = ("${geofenceModel.radius}");
  });
});
```

the error start from the "fromMap". Please help me to solve it

Comment: Is fromMap a function? maybe fromMap()?

Comment: Can you include your model class?

Comment: yes from geofenceModel(), but i don't know how to declare the coding in geofenceModel()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the parameters you mentioned (lat, long, rad) as type `String` for your `GeoFenceModel`, you need to create the `fromMap()` as follows:

```
class GeofenceModel {
  String latitude;
  String longitude;
  String radius;
  GeofenceModel({
    required this.latitude,
    required this.longitude,
    required this.radius,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'latitude': latitude,
      'longitude': longitude,
      'radius': radius,
    };
  }

  factory GeofenceModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return GeofenceModel(
      latitude: (map['latitude'] ?? '') as String,
      longitude: (map['longitude'] ?? '') as String,
      radius: (map['radius'] ?? '') as String,
    );
  }
}
```